# Django-admin custom command don't store cache value

Tags: python, django, caching

I've an unexpected behavior while using django command.

I'm using the standard Django cache system. My settings :

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
        'TIMEOUT': 0,
    }
}
```

This is my command code :

```
#coding: utf-8
import os
import sys
import time

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.cache import cache

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print(cache.get("mykey"))
        print(cache.set("mykey", "TEST", 300))
```

When I run it twice within the same minute I get the following output :

```
(venv_crypto_bot) macbook-pro:project dauzon$ python manage.py generate_data
None
None
(venv_crypto_bot) macbook-pro:project dauzon$ python manage.py generate_data
None
None
```

I'm on the dev server.

Clearly, Django don't store value in cache when I using a command. I don't know if it's due to I run the development server.

Cache runs correctly when I visiting the webpages of my dev server.

There are no details about the disabled cache (on command) in the Django documentation.

How can I store cache value within a Django custom command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem probably is that you are running [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) which is not shared through multiple process instances

> Note that each process will have its own private cache instance, which
>   means no cross-process caching is possible. This obviously also means
>   the local memory cache isn’t particularly memory-efficient, so it’s
>   probably not a good choice for production environments. It’s nice for
>   development.

Comment: It's that. Thank you. I'll try to go to memcached.